# C++ и графический интерфейс

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Всем привет , учусь C++ , есть ли альтернативы Visual Studio для разработки графического интерфейса программы?
У себя стоит ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

`1 - Qt Creator` , Сам спросил сам ответил.

Comment: Qt несколько больше, чем просто альтернатива MSVS. При должном обращении код, написанный на Qt не будет зависеть от платформы.

Comment: Qt конечно - самый популярный

Answer (score 4):

[wxFormBuilder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) (для библиотеки [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)), [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) (GTK+), [Juce](https://www.juce.com/)...

Answer (score 0):

Если речь именно о программах с возможностью "таскать" компоненты мышью для построения интерфейса, то [список таких программ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface_builder) довольно велик.

А краткий ответ на Ваш вопрос будет: **Да. Альтернатив полно.**